# Proof of Law of Total Probability of Expectation

Tags: probability

I am having some trouble understanding part of the proof for

$E(E(Y|X)) = E(Y)$

Specifically, the step (Degroot and Schervish 4E, p258):

$E(E(Y|X))$ = $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty}$ $E(Y|x) f(x) dx$

where $f(x)$ is the marginal pdf of RV X.

I understand that $E(Y|x)$ is the value and f(x) is its distribution. Thus, the integral of these would give the expected value of the random variable (Y|X). **What I don't understand is why f(x) is the distribution of $E(Y|X)$.**

Wikipedia explains the law of total probability as $E_{X}(E_{X|Y}(Y|X)) = E(Y)$
which means $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y*f(y|x)*f(x)dx$

This makes sense to me since the marginal pdf of X is the relevant distribution for the values of $E(Y|x)$. However, now I am confused as to why $E_{X}(*)$ would equal $E(Y)$; i.e., **what does the little subscript X in $E_{X}$ really mean?**

Edit 1:
I think I might have answered this myself. I believe for discrete RVs Y,X,Z, the $Pr(E(Y|x)) = z$ (arbitrary Z) is equal to the $Pr(X=x)$, hence they would have the same distribution. I would still love to know what the little subscript X means.

Comment: In general, the reason for the subscript $E_{W}(*)$ for some random variable $W$ is to emphasize that you will be finding expectation in accordance with the distribution of W

Comment: also note law of total expectation doesn't imply $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(y|x)f(x)dx$. It actually implies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(y|x)dy\right)f(x)dx$

Comment: You're right I fixed the post.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)$ is not the distribution of $E(Y|X)$, it's the density of $X$.
Note that $E(Y|X)$ is a function of $X$, and $E(E(Y|X)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty E(Y|x) f(x)\; dx$ follows from the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: Why is it not the distribution of E(Y|X)? I thought to get the expectation you need to integrate the value multiplied by its distribution (pdf). Also, assume Z = E(Y|X), then Pr(E(Y|x)) = z  is equal to Pr(X = x) for discrete RV's. Hence, Z and X have the same distribution.

Comment: They are not the same distribution, because $z$ is not $x$.